# Shiny: DataTable Active Rows Selection

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I'm trying to create a small app in Shiny that's an interface to create a new dataframe based on the selections from a couple of widgets in the app.

I have a DataTable that holds ~ 20 values, and then a few different radio buttons. 
The user clicks the rows they want active on the DT and then select their other parameters (radio buttons) and hit an action button to append the data to a dataframe (that starts off blank and adds rows each time). I have full functionality - but I'm having trouble grouping the DT rows in to one selection when they are chosen simultaneously.

Right now, the dataframe output looks like this:

```
EVENT NAME ACTION
A     John Reset
A     Adam Reset
A     James Reset
B     John Login
```

In this output, the user will choose event and actions from the radio buttons (in this case, EVENT 'A' and ACTION 'RESET') and then selects all 3 names to append the EVENT and ACTION to those users. When multiple rows are selected though, I want the values to be grouped as one NAME in the table.

Desired output:

```
EVENT NAME              ACTION
A     John, Adam, James Reset
C     John              Login
```

What can I change so that the selected rows from the DT are grouped together, rather than appended as a unique row?

This is my reactive string - I use this in my creation of the final dataframe:

```
Table.Reactive1 <- reactive({  
  s=input$table1_rows_selected
  #creating table
  eventsTable1 <- data.frame(EVENT = input$checkRadio1,
                             NAME = df1[s,  ],
                             ACTION = input$checkRadio2, 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  return(eventsTable1)
})
```

NOTE: 
The journey for the user goes:

```
1) DataTable -> Click the rows of names you want highlighted 
2) Radio button #1 -> Choose the EVENT category (A, B, C or D) 
3) Radio Button #2 -> Choose the ACTION (Reset, or login) 
4) Click action button to submit the 3 above choices and commit to a new DataTable output.
```

Comment: where does the "C     John              Login" row come from?

Comment: @Nate It's an example of another row of data added to the table. 

The journey for the user goes:
1) DataTable -> Click the rows of names you want highlighted
2) Radio button #1 -> Choose the EVENT category (A, B, C or D) 
3) Radio Button #2 -> Choose the ACTION (Reset, or login)
4) Click action button to submit the 3 above choices and commit to a new DataTable output.

Comment: Hi @wetcoaster may be this can help..[link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)